# users collection1 minus users collection2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.0.8

Lets say that I have two collections of users.

```
users1 = User.where(....)
users2 = User.where(....)
```

I need

```
users1 - users2
```

One way to get the solution is

```
ids = users1.map(&:id) - users2.map(&:id)
ids.map{ |i| User.find(i) }
```

Above code will work. However I was wondering if ActiveRecord implements some kind of equality operator so that I do not have to get ids from that collection.

Comment: `users1 - users2` works perfectly in console

Comment: Yes but I want to know if that can be trusted. My tests are passing so  it should be okay I guess.

Comment: if the tests are passing, then you can trust it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`users1 - users2` works perfectly, keep it simple!